# `cabal update` failed due to `out of memory`

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

Here is what `cabal update` outputs:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: out of memory (requested 2097152 bytes)
```

The reason may be shortage of memory. What about `tail 00-index.cache`?

```
pkg: charade 0.1 b# 46384
pkg: charset 0.0 b# 46390
pkg: charset 0.1 b# 46393
pkg: charset 0.2.0 b# 46396
pkg: charset 0.2.1 b# 46399
pkg: charset 0.2.2 b# 46402
pkg: charset 0.2.3 b# 46405
pkg: charset 0.3 b# 46408
pkg: charset 0.3.0.1 b# 46412
```

I can have `00-index.tar.gz` downloaded easily and have `00-index.tar` untared. However, because of `out of memory`, I cannot generate the cache file! Can cabal generate `00-index.cache` locally in an cheap way?

cabal --version

```
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: Am I reading that right? You don't have two megabytes of memory? ...and you're planning to build Haskell tools from source?

Comment: No! I did it successfully last time! It is located on VPS. @DanielWagner

Comment: @DanielWagner My assumption is that that's the size of the allocation that failed, not the total size of allocations.

Comment: Can you explain it? @DanielWagner

Comment: eccstartup: did you solve this eventually? Having the same issue

Comment: @franka Not sure. I suspect the 512M memory was not enough.

Comment: In case you're still struggling with the issue, @franka, I ran stormont's solution with swap spaces, and it worked!

Answer (score 19):

I ran into a similar problem running a micro instance on AWS (not running cabal update, but compiling my own program). I followed the suggestions in [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.beginners/6570) to create a swap space and it did the trick.

From the link:

```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/swap bs=1M count=1024
> mkswap /tmp/swap
> swapon /tmp/swap
```

The dd command creates a swap file with the name “swap” under the /tmp directory with a size of 1024MB (1GB).

Make this file as a swap file using the mkswap command.

Enable the newly created swapfile using the swapon command.

[This link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/)  has more information about swap spaces.

Comment: I just blindly ran these commands on my DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 14 (because its newly spun up and I have nothing to lose). It worked! Thanks stormont!

Comment: Why does this happen in the first place? 2097152 bytes ~ 2MB. Even on a t1 micro instance(the case where I'm running into this error) you have .613GiB ~ 600 MB of memory. If i run `top` before cabal update, it shows i have over half of this memory available so it seems like it should easily be able to handle this. Unless cabal itself is taking up most of that memory and the reported bytes requested are what's required for the install?

Comment: I think the requested bytes statement is just saying how much more cabal is looking for, not how much it has consumed. So, the OP was near his memory allocation limit when the extra 2MB's were requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put `00-index.cache` in the appropriate place, and `cabal-install` will use it just fine. To find out where to put it, look at the value of `remote-repo-cache` and `remote-repo` in `~/.cabal/config`; the cache should go in a directory named after the remote repo's nick inside the `remote-repo-cache` directory. For example, here's a snippet of my `config`:

```
remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
remote-repo-cache: /home/dmwit/.cabal/packages
```

and my cache is in `/home/dmwit/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.cache`.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding more memory to the machine on which you're running cabal update.

I once was trying to install GHC and compile some Haskell on a DigitalOcean bottom-tier server, and compilation always failed due to the lack of available RAM. Trying again on a more well-equipped server fixed the issue.